# How do I completely turn off Windows Defender from PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2016

`Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring` disables the first one, what are the specific switches to disable the others you see when you open the UI? I have not found a clear example of this in the docs and I don't feel like running EVERY disable switch because MS docs are bad.

[image]

Comment: I had to use "Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true" to disable it on Win10 1809.

Answer (score 15):

After going for hours through the docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/index?view=win10-ps

Just decided to uninstall it. This works on WS 2016 with PS 5.1.

```
Remove-WindowsFeature Windows-Defender, Windows-Defender-GUI
```

The below didn't work for me (from a blog dated 2011-2012), but give it a try before you uninstall:

```
Get-Service WinDefend | Stop-Service -PassThru | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
```

Later edit: Found a way for Windows 10, tested on 20H2 only. Please add a comment if it works for previous builds.

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" -Name DisableAntiSpyware -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on Win10 (tested on v1809).

Answer (score 3):

from windows server 2016 you could try

uninstall-windowsfeature -name windowsserverantimalware

Answer (score 2):

For example you can use something like this - >
Run PowerShell console as Administrator - > Paste to console and hit enter

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableIntrusionPreventionSystem $true -DisableIOAVProtection $true -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true -DisableScriptScanning $true -EnableControlledFolderAccess Disabled -EnableNetworkProtection AuditMode -Force -MAPSReporting Disabled -SubmitSamplesConsent NeverSend
```

Full list of options with description available at: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/set-mppreference?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 1):

I needed to disable Windows defender because I installed a software which I modified with orca (MSI modification), and defender kind of blocked it.
Found this "long" solution on this [link](https://bidouillesecurity.com/disable-windows-defender-in-powershell/). I tested it on Windows 10 version 21H2. It gives me then the following answer, which looks good.

[image: Antivirus disabled]

Just make a new `disableDefender.ps1` file and write the following code inside

```
if(-Not $($(whoami) -eq "nt authority\system")) {
    $IsSystem = $false

    # Elevate to admin (needed when called after reboot)
    if (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
        Write-Host "    [i] Elevate to Administrator"
        $CommandLine = "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
        Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine
        Exit
    }

    # Elevate to SYSTEM if psexec is available
    $psexec_path = $(Get-Command PsExec -ErrorAction 'ignore').Source 
    if($psexec_path) {
        Write-Host "    [i] Elevate to SYSTEM"
        $CommandLine = " -i -s powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments 
        Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -FilePath $psexec_path -ArgumentList $CommandLine
        exit
    } else {
        Write-Host "    [i] PsExec not found, will continue as Administrator"
    }

} else {
    $IsSystem = $true
}
67..90|foreach-object{
    $drive = [char]$_
    Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "$($drive):\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Add-MpPreference -ExclusionProcess "$($drive):\*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

Write-Host "    [+] Disable scanning engines (Set-MpPreference)"

Set-MpPreference -DisableArchiveScanning 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -DisableBehaviorMonitoring 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -DisableIntrusionPreventionSystem 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -DisableIOAVProtection 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -DisableRemovableDriveScanning 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -DisableBlockAtFirstSeen 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -DisableScanningMappedNetworkDrivesForFullScan 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -DisableScanningNetworkFiles 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -DisableScriptScanning 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Write-Host "    [+] Set default actions to Allow (Set-MpPreference)"

Set-MpPreference -LowThreatDefaultAction Allow -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -ModerateThreatDefaultAction Allow -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-MpPreference -HighThreatDefaultAction Allow -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$need_reboot = $false

# WdNisSvc Network Inspection Service 
# WinDefend Antivirus Service
# Sense : Advanced Protection Service

$svc_list = @("WdNisSvc", "WinDefend", "Sense")
foreach($svc in $svc_list) {
    if($(Test-Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$svc")) {
        if( $(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$svc").Start -eq 4) {
            Write-Host "        [i] Service $svc already disabled"
        } else {
            Write-Host "        [i] Disable service $svc (next reboot)"
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$svc" -Name Start -Value 4
            $need_reboot = $true
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "        [i] Service $svc already deleted"
    }
}

Write-Host "    [+] Disable drivers"

# WdnisDrv : Network Inspection System Driver
# wdfilter : Mini-Filter Driver
# wdboot : Boot Driver

$drv_list = @("WdnisDrv", "wdfilter", "wdboot")
foreach($drv in $drv_list) {
    if($(Test-Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$drv")) {
        if( $(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$drv").Start -eq 4) {
            Write-Host "        [i] Driver $drv already disabled"
        } else {
            Write-Host "        [i] Disable driver $drv (next reboot)"
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$drv" -Name Start -Value 4
            $need_reboot = $true
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "        [i] Driver $drv already deleted"
    }
}

# Check if service running or not
if($(GET-Service -Name WinDefend).Status -eq "Running") {   
    Write-Host "    [+] WinDefend Service still running (reboot required)"
    $need_reboot = $true
} else {
    Write-Host "    [+] WinDefend Service not running"
}
$link_reboot = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\disable-defender.lnk"
Remove-Item -Force "$link_reboot" -ErrorAction 'ignore' # Remove the link (only execute once after reboot)

if($need_reboot) {
    Write-Host "    [+] This script will be started again after reboot." -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor White

    $powershell_path = '"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"'
    $cmdargs = "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments

    $res = New-Item $(Split-Path -Path $link_reboot -Parent) -ItemType Directory -Force
    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
    $shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($link_reboot)
    $shortcut.TargetPath = $powershell_path
    $shortcut.Arguments = $cmdargs
    $shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "$(Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent)"
    $shortcut.Save()
} else {
    if($IsSystem) {

        # Configure the Defender registry to disable it (and the TamperProtection)
        # editing HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\ requires to be SYSTEM

        Write-Host "    [+] Disable all functionnalities with registry keys (SYSTEM privilege)"

        # Cloud-delivered protection:
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection" -Name SpyNetReporting -Value 0
        # Automatic Sample submission
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection" -Name SubmitSamplesConsent -Value 0
        # Tamper protection
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features" -Name TamperProtection -Value 4

        # Disable in registry
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender" -Name DisableAntiSpyware -Value 1
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" -Name DisableAntiSpyware -Value 1

    } else {
        Write-Host "    [W] (Optional) Cannot configure registry (not SYSTEM)"
    }


    if($MyInvocation.UnboundArguments -And $($MyInvocation.UnboundArguments.tolower().Contains("-delete"))) {

        # Delete Defender files

        function Delete-Show-Error {
            $path_exists = Test-Path $args[0]
            if($path_exists) {
                Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path $args[0]
            } else {
                Write-Host "    [i] $($args[0]) already deleted"
            }
        }

        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "[+] Delete Windows Defender (files, services, drivers)"

        # Delete files
        Delete-Show-Error "C:\ProgramData\Windows\Windows Defender\"
        Delete-Show-Error "C:\ProgramData\Windows\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\"

        # Delete drivers
        Delete-Show-Error "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\wd\"

        # Delete service registry entries
        foreach($svc in $svc_list) {
            Delete-Show-Error "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$svc"
        }

        # Delete drivers registry entries
        foreach($drv in $drv_list) {
            Delete-Show-Error "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\$drv"
        }
    }
}
Write-Host "Script Finished" -foregroundcolor Yellow
```

Comment: I can't downvote, but here's my warning: This script breaks the service completely for me. I'm unable to turn it back on after running the script even after a reboot.

Comment: Actually there is an update to my post. I did not mention that Windows made it on purpose impossible to turn completely off Windows defender's real time protection, you can only turn off some features like cloud based protection, but it will always remain active somehow, even with this script. to be able to turn it off completely you must manually turn off "Tampler protection", because this is what windows wants to avoid, to be able to turn off Defender protection by script. Now I am not saying that its not possible with any kind of malware, kali linux attack or something like that.

Comment: To answer your question, you should be able to turn it on again manually but the script makes some reboot tasks. To avoid it get to this path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp" and delete \disable-defender.lnk script because this causes the defender of windows to turn off completely

Comment: This script worked well for me, but you need to run it in Windows Safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

To disable Real-time Protection

> ```
> Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
> ```

Disable Automatic Sample Submission

> ```
> Set-MpPreference -SubmitSamplesConsent NeverSend
> ```

Disable Cloud-Based Protection

> ```
> Set-MpPreference -MAPSReporting Disable
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Verified on Win11 Enterprise 22H2 default install:

Since WinDefend is a special protected app, the supported ways to disable are via SCCM/Intune/etc, or when different AV used instead.

So only possible complete solution requires: sc.exe, & another app with TI rights, so we can modify relevant services:
[Nirsoft - AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html)

We need to make 2 files:

`%windir%\script-ps` with contents:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
Get-Service WinDefend | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
Get-Service Sense | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
Get-Service mpssvc | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
Get-Service WdNisSvc | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
sc.exe config WinDefend binPath=%windir%\bfsvc.exe
```

`NoDefend.cfg` with contents:

```
[General]
EXEFilename=
CommandLine=(gc script-ps) | iex
StartDirectory=%windir%
WaitProcess=0
PriorityClass=32
WindowState=0
UseWindowPosition=0
WindowPosition=20,20
UseWindowSize=0
WindowSize=640,400
RunAs=8
RunAsProcessName=
EnvironmentVariablesMode=1
OSCompatMode=0
UseSearchPath=0
ParseVarCommandLine=1
UseAffinityMask=0
AffinityMask=0 1
Compat640480=0
CompatDisableVisualThemes=0
CompatDisableDesktopComp=0
CompatDisableFullScreenOpt=0
CompatHighDPI=0
CompatColors=0
RunAsUserName=
RunAsDomain=
RunFromService=0
ComputerName=
RunMode=4
ShellExecuteAction=
CommandWindowMode=2
[EnvironmentVariables]
Lines=0
WinPos=2C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 65 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 9A 03 00 00 A0 02 00 00
```

---

Now run this in CMD - Admin:

```
AdvancedRun.exe /Run NoDefend.cfg
```

Hidden PS window runs & execs cmds (not script so no need to bypass PS restrictions) in `%windir%\script-ps`

Wait a second for it all to run, then reboot, & then all except WinDefend will be disabled.
Somehow WinDefend will be set to Manual, & so it tries starting, but fails since we changed its exe to different lolbin that does nothing with 0 args. Ignore that service:
We have great success of "completely turned off Windows Defender"

While this works for now, it might not in future if M$ patches this "Answer".

---

If you want to re-enable again, change the cmds to Enable & change binPath to its current location, like:

```
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\<version>\MsMpEng.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not recommended to turn off Windows Defender completely as it provides essential security features to your Windows operating system. However, if you need to disable it temporarily for troubleshooting or other reasons, you can do so using PowerShell with administrator privileges.

Here's how you can disable Windows Defender using PowerShell:

Open PowerShell as an administrator. You can do this by right-clicking on the PowerShell icon and selecting "Run as Administrator".

Use the following command to disable real-time protection for Windows Defender:

sql
Copy code
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
This will turn off real-time protection for Windows Defender.

Use the following command to disable the cloud-based protection feature for Windows Defender:

sql
Copy code
Set-MpPreference -DisableIntrusionPreventionSystem $true
This will disable the cloud-based protection feature for Windows Defender.

Finally, use the following command to disable Windows Defender completely:

sql
Copy code
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true -DisableIntrusionPreventionSystem $true
This will disable both real-time protection and cloud-based protection features for Windows Defender.